Azure Logic App Local Debugging - Getting DirectApiAuthorizationRequired Error
I'm developing an Azure Logic App (Standard) locally using Visual Studio Code on macOS, and I'm encountering a DirectApiAuthorizationRequired error when trying to invoke my HTTP trigger endpoint.
The following message is displayed when I hit the webhook URL the terminal command gives me:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "DirectApiAuthorizationRequired",
        "message": "The authentication scheme is required. Please add authentication scheme and try again."
    }
}

How do I disable this or resolve this? This workflow is copied from a hosted version which also has no authentication.

You need to right click on the workflow.json file and click Overview, this will show you the full URL you need to use. You need to ignore the URL they provide in the terminal when you start the app as it doesn't include all the necessary parameters.
I found the answer watching this video.
